# "Filtering" input data for analysis in Python

Tags: python, statistics, signal-processing, data-processing

I have a large set of data on which I have to perform a lot of serach operations. In order to reduce the number of data points, the data is "compressed" by merging every continuous positive-slope or negative-slope point into a single point representing a local maximum or minimum, and also recording the number of original data points that the new point represents.

For example, if my data points are 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 1, the compressed data is recorded as:

2,1 - represents the initial value of 2 with a local min after 1 cycle

6,4 - represents the local max of 6 which occured after 3 more cycles

1,2 - represents the local min of 1 which occured after 2 more cycles

Is this some sort of decimation or downsampling filter?

Thanks in advance.